# Find all the Url in String

Tags: c#, regex

while using this regex i'm not able to find the url if the Url is Something like 
CIO.in ,Compgterworld.iq,ChannelWorld.in etc.
Instead this regex take the Email id as url.
How can i exclude the Email id and take those url as valid url.

```
 const string MatchUrlPattern = 
   @"(^(http[s]?://)?([w]{3}[.])?([a-z0-9]+[.])+com(((/[a-z0-9]+)*(/[a-z0-9]+/))*([a-z0-9]+[.](html|php|gif|png))?)$)|(^([.]/)?((([a-z0-9]+)/?)+|(([a-z0-9]+)/)+([a-z0-9]+[.](html|php|gif|png)))?$)";

 Regex urlrx = new Regex(MatchUrlPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 MatchCollection urlmatches = rx.Matches(contentString);

 int urlnoOfMatches = matches.Count;

 foreach (Match match in urlmatches)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(match.Value.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Are [Uri.TryCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572(v=vs.90).aspx) and [IsWellFormedUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) giving you wrong result?

Comment: But `@` can be valid in every URL RFC.. for exemple `http://-.~_!$&'()*+,;=:%40:80%2f::::::@example.com` is a valid URL

Comment: Don;t Get it .
i Just need a Regex  to Find the Urls in the string. Urls are like
CIO.in 
Compgterworld.iq
ChannelWorld.in @DragandDrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex for your all test scenarios

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\S*)?
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's a good idea to filter URL that way, but if you still want to capture those then use this:

```
    ((http|ftp|https)://)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?
```

I used that on this page text as an input and it gave me these results:

```
    CIO.in
    Compgterworld.iq,ChannelWorld.in
    RegexOptions.Compiled
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    rx.Matches
    matches.Count
    Console.WriteLine
    match.Value.ToString
    Path.Combine
    3.0
    2017.9.24.27120
```

That's what I mean it's not ideal to filter it that way

Comment: It Won't Work @Riz